# Typescript error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: windows, typescript

I want to do:

```
let server = {}
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    server[i] = 'none';
}
```

but I get this annoying error saying that my element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature. My code works but I get all these errors. Is there a way to disable them with gulp by passing a compiler flag or make the element explicit?

Comment: It seems like you're actually creating an array, in which case why not use `new Array(20)`? Or just define the index signature, `{ [index: number]: string }`. You can turn off the no implicit any checking, but if you're going to use TypeScript you might as well use it properly.

Comment: When I do index:numer thing I get 3 syntax errors and and about 50 more semantic errors, the code is a bit longer than my example above

Comment: @jonrsharpe how is that an array? you can insert numbers into an object perfectly fine

Comment: Well without a [mcve] that's all I can offer.

Comment: @Andrew yes, an array is basically just an object whose keys are numbers. But semantically what the OP is building seems more array-like than object-like, so why not use the type system to reinforce that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I use Typescript for this one small part of my hobby project and have no interest in this part being neat nor secure. You mentioned that I can turn off the no implicit, how do I do that?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html, but if you have other problems that might not solve all of them

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am aware arrays are actually objects. But you don't have the prototype that gives it every attribute an array has that an object doesn't. Maybe the object is just built for a collection or there are other algorithms that OP is building on top of.

Comment: @Andrew it was just a suggestion. I said *"in that case"*; the OP, and you, can take it or leave it as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare it as type `any`. There might be some compiler options you need to switch as well

```
let server: any = {}
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    server[i] = 'none';
}
```

The file is called `tsconfig.json` and it should be in your root directory.
Here is what mine looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2018",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false, //here
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you know where your typescript config file is?

Comment: Nope didn't even know typescript had a config file

Comment: I am on Windows 8 so I don't have a 'root directory'. Do you know where it could be on Windows? Edit: found it :)

Comment: @displaynammemem. I mean the root directory of your web app.

Comment: @displaynammemem note comments aren't valid in JSON, so don't just copy paste that line

Comment: @jonrsharpe FYI comments are allowed in tsconfig

Comment: @AlekseyL. [so they are](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4987); my bad, thanks for pointing that out. Weird they don't mention it in the actual config page in the docs...